# Multiple fast saves on the same entity with Breeze using WebApiOData adapter

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, breeze

I'm using Breeze with an auto save mechanisms (triggering on EntityAction.PropertyChange) and together with the SaveQueueing extension. This works generally fine.
The problem occurs in the case when an entity is changed, a save is triggered, and during the save another change on the same entity happens. In this case another save is queued. But as soon as the first save finishes the entity state becomes unmodified.

Is it somehow possible to handle this scenario with breeze?

Update: Here's a [Pull Request](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/pull/28) for a testcase which reproduces the problem with the SaveQueueing extension (version 2.0) together with the WebApiOData adapter.

Comment: I know how to deal with that. Give me a little time :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote saveQueuing, ground up. Now [v.2.0 in github](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.labs/blob/master/breeze.savequeuing.js). It covers your scenario as it should have from the start. Look at the comments at the top of the file to see the known limitations.

I've also updated the samples that use it. See the [Angular-Todo sample](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/tree/master/net/Todo-Angular).

I remain uncomfortable with this auto-save experience particularly as potential for mischief goes up with long network latencies.

Best of luck.

### Update 28 Nov

Since re-writing `saveQueuing` I have tried to reproduce the failing use case you've described in your comments ... and cannot.

Here is [my QUnit test from DocCode](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/blob/master/net/DocCode/DocCode/tests/saveQueuingTests.js). Tell me what I'm missing.

```
asyncTest("saves DIFFERENT modified value of MODIFIED entity when saved before 1st save completes", function () {
    expect(4);

    var todo = em.createEntity('TodoItem', {
        Description: 'Test',
        IsDone: false
    });
    em.saveChanges()
      .then(modAndSave)
      .then(requery)
      .then(success)
      .catch(handleFail).finally(start);

    function modAndSave(){
        // modify the existing Todo
        todo.setProperty('Description', 'Test mod 1');

        // save the first mod
        em.saveChanges().catch(handleFail);

        equal(todo.getProperty('IsDone'), false,
            "isDone is false while 1st save in progress, just before mod");

        // modify different property while the 1st save is in progress
        todo.setProperty('IsDone', true);

        // save now, before the first save response
        return em.saveChanges();
    }

    // 2nd save callback
    function requery(sr){ 
        em.clear(); // paranoia.
        return breeze.EntityQuery.from('Todos')
            .where('Id', 'eq', todo.getProperty('Id'))
            .using(em).execute();
    }

    function success(data) {
        todo = data.results[0];
        var aspect = todo.entityAspect;
        equal(aspect.entityState.name, 'Unchanged',
            "double modified Todo was saved, requeried, and is Unchanged");
        equal(todo.getProperty('Description'), 'Test mod 1',
            "description has the modified value, 'Test mod 1'");
        equal(todo.getProperty('IsDone'), true,
            "isDone has the value modified (true) during 1st save");
    }
});
```

When I run this test and examine the network traffic, I see THREE "saveChanges" requests

1. the creation of the Todo (Description = 'Test', IsDone = false)

   `{Id: -1, Description: "Test", CreatedAt: "1900-01-01T08:00:00.000Z", IsDone: false}`
2. the first modification (the one setting Description to 'Test mod 1')

   `{Id: 79, Description: "Test mod 1", CreatedAt: "1900-01-01T08:00:00.000Z", IsDone: false}`
3. the second modification (the one setting IsDone to true);

   `{Id: 79, Description: "Test mod 1", CreatedAt: "1900-01-01T08:00:00.000Z", IsDone: true}`

Comment: Hi Ward. Many thanks for the new version. Really appreciated! Unfortunately I cannot get it working in my use case.

Comment: My use case is:
* Change EntityA.PropertyA
* Trigger 1. Save
* Change EntityA.PropertyB
* Trigger 2. Save
* 1. Save finishes

If I have a look at ` EntityMemo.prototype.applyAfterSave` the second change is in `memo.pendingChanges` after the first save returns, but it compares the value of `memo.pendingChanges['PropertyB']` with `saved.getProperty('PropertyB')`, which at this time is the equal (new) value in my case.

Comment: Good use case. Missed it in my tests. I'll work on that one. Stay tuned.

Comment: [Added test](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/blob/master/net/DocCode/DocCode/tests/saveQueuingTests.js) for your use case: "saves DIFFERENT modified value of MODIFIED entity when saved before 1st save completes". The test passes. Either I misunderstand your use case or you didn't report it precisely. Is it possible that the first save finishes AFTER the modification but BEFORE the second save? In that case, Breeze does revert your change and saveQueuing neither can nor should do anything about that; see this test: "the save response overwrites changes to entity made during save".

Comment: I'm re-reading your comment and wondering why you would expect a second save when `memo.pendingChanges.propB` === `saved.propB`. If there is no difference, there is no reason to save again, right? I'm confused.

Comment: The problem is that the model has the correct values but there was never a save request for the second change happening.
My case runs like this:

    1. EntityA.PropertyA is changed
    2. Save is triggered
    3. Save request starts
    4. EntityB.PropertyB is changed
    5. Save is triggered. Adds to queue
    6. 1st save returns

Now EntityB.PropertyB is already at the new value, and therefore the second save doesn't happen. It looks fine from a model perspective, but the changes are not actually saved to the backend.

Comment: Sorry I seem to be too stupid for SO comment syntax for lists... Just didn't get it to format correctly

Comment: I will look again at my test when I get home as I believe I am testing for that but may have overlooked something. To be absolutely certain I can requery after what I THINK is the second save.

Comment: Thanks! Otherwise I can give you access to my test environment where you can reproduce it, if you like.

Comment: Look at my test in my updated answer. What are we doing differently?

Comment: I think this is my use case. But it is only checking the state and values of the model after the second save. This works also for me. My problem is that the second save doesn't make the OData post request, since the values are already correct (But they are only correct in the entity, never posted to the backend). Are you sure the second save actually makes something in your test case?

Comment: I did a requery to verify that the values are in the DB and not just in the client. I even cleared the cache before the requery (paranoia). I confirm that the `IsDone` is false between the 1st and 2nd saves; therefore, if there was no 2nd save, the `IsDone` would be false upon requery. But the test proves that it is true upon requery so the second save must have written to the db.

Comment: I confirmed the three saves in the network traffic and updated my answer in that regard.

Comment: These are KO tests. Are you using KO or Angular? I'll go try them in Ng too.

Comment: There is no difference with Angular. I just confirmed that tests pass in Angular (see the evolving [ngDocCode project](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/tree/master/node/ngDocCode) which now has a ["saveQueuing.spec.js"](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/blob/master/node/ngDocCode/public/test/server_specs/saveQueuing.spec.js).

Comment: I just tried to run the DocCode tests on my Windows 8.1 machine using Chrome 39. There are several test cases failing, one of them is the "saves DIFFERENT modified value of MODIFIED entity when saved before 1st save completes" test case (fails on 4th step: isDone has the value modified (true) during 1st save). 
Do I need to do something special to have the tests pass?

Comment: That is EXACTLY my environment. The DocCode tests use KO but should pass. Ahhh. The checked in DocCode did NOT have savequeuing v.2!  I just checked that in. Be sure you have v.2, not v.1

Comment: I think I found the difference: I'm using the `webApiOData` data service. 

This seems to be the problem: Before the OData request it retrieves the contentKeys (https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js/blob/master/src/b00_breeze.dataService.odata.js#L120). During the OData request, I make my second save, modifying the model. In the success callback of the OData request it returns the model from the contentKeys (https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js/blob/master/src/b00_breeze.dataService.odata.js#L156), which now is the modified model. Therefore the second save never will happen.

Comment: I'm away this week. I'll ponder this when I get back.

Comment: did you already found time to look into this? Or should I better add it as an issue on GitHub?

Comment: Sorry ... I haven't. I have a hard time summoning the energy or courage to fight with Web API OData. Would you be willing to make a repro on plunker?

Comment: We have now implemented a test case. Please see the following [pull request](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/pull/28) on the breeze.js.samples repo.
Hope this helps to resolve the issue.

Comment: I think I got it nailed with the latest [commit 8dd59db19e](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/commit/8dd59db19ed94dfc02b471fc13b6e0ed4cab7032). The [OData test](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/blob/master/net/DocCode/DocCode/tests/odataTests.js) now passes and I added some more tests to [saveQueuingTests.js](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/blob/master/net/DocCode/DocCode/tests/saveQueuingTests.js). PLEASE mark as ANSWERED once you feel I've done it.

Comment: It seems to work fine with 2.0.1 (and 2.0.2). Thanks for all your effort!